# Authy Desktop URL Scheme

Tags: javascript, html, twilio, authy

I was just wondering if anyone knows how to open the Twilio Authy Desktop app for windows with a URL scheme? Something like the default windows one's ex: ms-settings://

Answer (score 0):

you can open with authy://open